# Properly setting up an alertdialog on Activity closing?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have an activity with two score numbers. I want the user to choose a winner if they're the same when it closes (i.e. player 1 or player2). As a .NET person, I'm trying to basically do the MessageBox.

Unfortunately, from what I've read, android doesn't do UI threads the same way. And that the activity has "a leaked window". I looked on SO and I saw the idea was to put "dismiss" in "onPause". However, I didn't see a "onPause" function and was confused to how to implement it. So I tried what I have below, but got the same error.

What can I do to this guy in order to make sure this works properly?

```
  public void onFinish(View v) {
    //get scores
    TextView score1tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScore1);
     score1 = score1tv.getText().toString();
    TextView score2tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScore2);
     score2 = score2tv.getText().toString();

    //Make sure they aren't the same
    int i_Score1 = Integer.parseInt(score1);
    int i_Score2 = Integer.parseInt(score2);

    if (i_Score1 == i_Score2){

      //alert user
      new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Duplicate score")
                .setMessage("Whose score won the bout?")
                .setPositiveButton(boutData[1], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //fencer 1 won
                        score1 = "V" + score1;
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(boutData[3], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        score2 = "V" + score2;
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("edittextvalue","value_here");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

**Edit**: Here's the solution I came to thanks to the help I received:

```
 public void onFinish(View v) {
    //get scores
    TextView score1tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScore1);
     score1 = score1tv.getText().toString();
    TextView score2tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScore2);
     score2 = score2tv.getText().toString();

    //Make sure they aren't the same
    int i_Score1 = Integer.parseInt(score1);
    int i_Score2 = Integer.parseInt(score2);

    if (score1 == score2){

      //alert user
      new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Duplicate score")
                .setMessage("Whose score won the bout?")
                .setPositiveButton(boutData[1], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //fencer 1 won
                        score1 = "V" + score1;

                        //close out
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra("edittextvalue","value_here");
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        finish();
                       }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(boutData[3], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        score2 = "V" + score2;

                        //close out
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra("edittextvalue","value_here");
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        finish();

                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
    else{
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("edittextvalue","value_here");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the last four lines into an else clause and do something similar in your onClick methods.

Also you shouldn't have to call dialog.dismiss() manually.